# Silicone molds: transportation and storage

Tags: utensils, silicone

I'm not quite sure if this is a proper question for this website, but I hope it is.
My question regards silicone molds you'd use in patisserie for baking (like cakes) or freezing (like mousses).

I am considering bringing back from a trip overseas some items, including silicone molds. However, I'm afraid if packing them in luggage or airplane travel could significantly damage the molds, for instance by leaving dents in them. Should I be worried? Are there any particular precautions I should take when transporting them? Of course, I understand they should be kept away from objects that could cut or tear them.

Since we're already here, I think I'll make the question a bit more general and ask about storage. Is there any care in particular one should take when storing them in order for them to keep their forms or otherwise quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a couple of silicone cupcake moulds (only cheap ones), and they recover their shape instantly after being stored at the bottom of a pile of cake tins for months (I don't use them as often as many of my metal baking utensils). If they're the same as mine, you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: I went ahead and ordered the molds and today I got them in perfect state. Very good!